# How to display the corresponding table value of the response in AJAX

Tags: laravel

I have an ajax response that is equal to 1. And,in my success function, I want to display not the 1 to my view but the corresponding column_name which is 'brands_name' in the brands table which is 'Apple' in this case. I want to display this after a successful post request. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to send your response from your controller (json)

// controller

```
$data['ajax_response'] = 1;
$data['brands_name'] = $brands_name;
return json_encode($data);
```

2. You need to catch the success function to get the variable you want from php

// javascript

```
$.ajax({
    url:link,
    dataType:"json",
    data:data,
    type:"post",
    success: function(data)
    {
        if(data.ajax_response == 1)
        {
            console.log(data.brands_name);
        }
    },
    error: function()
    {

    }
});
```